# Should I use GET or POST in the API when I want to query data based on an ID passed by the user to the nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js, api, rest

router.post()
or
router.get()?

when I want to GET data based on a particular ID passed to the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET  --> To get data
POST --> To create/update resource(s)
```

In your case you need to query some data based on user. What you can do is you can pass your user-id as a URL parameter or query parameter. It should be a `GET` request.

example:

Pass user-id as a URL parameter

```
[GET] https://www.example.com/api/v1/post/100
```

pass user-id as a query parameter

```
[GET] https://www.example.com/api/v1/post?user-id=100
```